# Node server won't start, gives unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Every time I try to start my server it gives me a long error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/isal/routes/index.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

The file with the syntax error is this index.js file It claims that there is a parsing error, unexpected token with the final line, but has nothing after unexpected token and I don't really see the problem with the module exporting.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var imgur = require('../services/imgur');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello');
});

router.get('/latest', function(req, res) {

});

router.get('/search/:q', function(req, res) {
    imgur.getImage(req.params.q, req.query.offset).then(ans => {
        res.json(ans);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Look at `/home/ubuntu/workspace/isal/routes/index.js`. You have a syntax error. We can't fix it without seeing that file on line 5. (`5:15` tells you the line and column in the file to look at)

Comment: Try to check line 53 in your main app file

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added the content from the file with the issue.

Comment: You're missing a `});` in your last `router.get` call. (Once you've seen this comment, I suggest just deleting the question.)

Comment: You're missing a `})` pair. You're closing the function you're passing to `router.get` but you aren't closing the arrow function you're passing to `then`.

Comment: Separately: If you're using an older version of Node, it may not support arrow functions (which would explain why the error points to the `=`). Current versions of Node **do** support arrow functions.

Comment: Yeah I was learning on the go with someone using es6 I believe which I haven't really learned, I was trying to change them to normal function form but that one I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are not properly closing your final function call:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var imgur = require('../services/imgur');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello'); 
});

router.get('/latest', function(req, res) {

});

router.get('/search/:q', function(req, res) {
    imgur.getImage(req.params.q, req.query.offset).then(ans => {
        res.json(ans);
    }); <---------------- Missing
});

module.exports = router;
```

When you get a syntax error like this, it basically means start from where the error occurred, and backtrack up in your file until you find the syntax error. There will *always* be a syntax error, if a syntax error is thrown. You should be using a tool to code with syntax highlighting and save yourself a world of problems, like an IDE.

Comment: While this didn't solve the entire server issue. It did fix one of the issues causing it and helped lead me to the full solution. So this works.